# Parameter value is out of range

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

It seems EF is padding zeros to the value that I'm trying to save and then throwing an exception.  Here is my code:  Why is the total hours field with a value of 10.17 out of range of a decimal(6,5) value type and why is it padding this value with zeros?  Saving this value directly using SQL Server Management Studio doesn't seem to be a problem, so it seems more like a problem with EF.

This is from a database first .edmx file.  I've tried setting the scale and precision and setting to none.  Neither have worked

```
 var rVal = new Data.FactPayrollHour()
                {
                    BereavementHours = 0.0M,
                    CostCenter = "MyCostCenter",
                    Department = "MyDepartment",
                    EmergencyHours = 0.0M,
                    HomeGroupCode = "MyHomeGroup",
                    PayrollEmployeeId = employees.FirstOrDefault().Id,
                    PayType = "MyPayType",
                    PunchDateKey = dateDims.FirstOrDefault().ID,
                    Schedule = "",
                    ServiceHours = 0.0M,
                    Shift = "",
                    ShortTermHours = 0.0M,
                    TimePolicy = "",
                    TotalHours = 10.17M,
                    UnpaidHours = 0.0M,
                    VacationHours = 0.0M
                };
                db.FactPayrollHours.Add(rVal);
                db.SaveChanges();
```

The exception message is: `Parameter value '10.17000' is out of range.`

Stack Trace:

```
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteRPC(SqlCommand cmd, _SqlRPC[] rpcArray, Int32 timeout, Boolean inSchema, SqlNotificationRequest notificationRequest, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isCommandProc, Boolean sync, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 startRpc, Int32 startParam)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
```

Comment: `decimal(6,5)` means: 6 total number of decimal digits to be stored, of which 5 to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: If the type is decimal(6,5) you can't possibly store 10.17 in it by SSMS. Are you sure you're always in the same database? The display `10.17000` is in keeping with the scale of the decimal, and it's just for display.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the data type is `decimal(6,5)` you can use up to 6 total decimal digits, 5 of which will be reserved for after the decimal point (that is why you have additional 0-es after the decimal point).

That leaves you with 1 digit before (on the left of) the decimal point. And you are using 2.
That is why you have the error.

Comment: Yup, that was it.  I had a misunderstanding of the precision attribute.  I had thought it was the digits to the left, not the total number of digits.  It is clear now.  Thank you!