# Error handling with Dapper Plus BulkInsert

Tags: dapper-plus

I am using `BulkInsert` API from `Z.Dapper.Plus` and it is failing due to bad data and the message is `Parameter value '7900000000000000.000000' is out of range.`
Is there a way to improve this message so I can readily identity the specific row causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to improve the message in Dapper Plus. That's an error message from SQL Server that your value cannot be stored in your current data type (pretty similar to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56349937/5619143)

You currently have the value in error, so the easiest way to find the row in error is probably to look at your datasource to which entity has this value. Or also by adding a validation that no value is out of bound with your data type.

Another way is to set a `BatchSize = 1` and look with SQL Profiler when the error will be thrown. You will have all information about the row in error by looking at the SQL.

Comment: It is weird, because I was not getting the error when doing single row insert in a loop.

Comment: Anand, can you provide the full error message and stack trace. You don't get the error probably because the error comes when doing a `SqlBulkCopy` (which is not used when the `BatchSize = 1`). We want to make sure that we might sometimes like to fix or add an option to fix this kind of error.